# Updating Entities in symfony-2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I created entities from my database using the following command

```
#1 php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/ doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force

#2 php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeDemoBundle yml

#3 php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeDemoBundle
```

After that I may alter some tables in the database.

What steps should I follow to reflect the changes in the symfony-framework?

Answer (score 4):

You should not alter your database outside of Symfony2. Now you should update by hand YML configuration files and run #3 command again or overwrite your entities from [database schema directly](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)